# parametrization of intersection of sphere and plane

Tags: real-analysis, curves, parametrization

Let's consider the sphere centered at point $(0,0,-1)$ which is defined by the equation $x^2+y^2+(z+1)^2=4$. We are interested in a parametric expression of the intersection of that sphere with the plane $x=z$.

I have already found many questions here on MSE on this or related problems but they rely on a trick where you do some manipulations that finally lead to a nice quadratic form. In my case I haven't found such a trick.

---

Manipulating the equations I get:
$$
2x^2+2x+1+y^2=4.
$$
It resembles an ellipsis but I don't know how to get rid of the $2x$ term.
What I have found out by playing around with the parametrization of an ellipsis is that $\varphi:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}^3$, where
$$
\varphi(t)=\begin{cases}\varphi_1(t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(t)\\\varphi_2(t)=2\sin(t)\\\varphi_3(t)=-1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(t),\end{cases}
$$
satisfies the equation $2x^2+2x+1+y^2=4.$ But how do I know that the converse is true, i.e. that a solution of $2x^2+2x+1+y^2=4$ can be always represented by $\varphi$?

Comment: $(x+\frac 12)^2 =x^2+x+\frac 14$

Comment: The sphere $x^2+y^2+(z+1)^2=4$ is centered at $(0,0,-1)$, not at $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: @PierreCarre, thanks I should really practise more "completing the square".